# How to specify multiple TimestampType and DataType formats while reading CSV to dataframe in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The CSV file I am reading contains 3 columns. Below are the format of the columns.

1. Format of DateTime1 is "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
2. Format of DateTime2 is "dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss"
3. Format of Date is "mm/dd/yyyy"

The below code allows one timeformat for all the columns.

```
schema_datatype = StructType([StructField('DateTime1',TimestampType(),True),
StructField('DateTime2',TimestampType(),True),
StructField('Date',DataType(),True)])


df= spark.read.csv(header=True,\
path="sample.csv",\
schema=schema_datatype, \
timestampFormat="mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
```

But how do I specify date format per column while using read.csv.
PS: I am using Spark 2.1.0

Thanks

Comment: I do not think you can do that, however, I could be wrong. A work-around would be to read the columns as strings and then do the conversion to `TimeStamp` afterwards.

Comment: Yes but that would be computationally inefficient to do in 2 steps on Bigdata right

Comment: I do not believe it will be too bad, can't be compared to `join`, etc. You can use the `unix_timestamp` to try it out.

Comment: Agree with the first comment, early or later, we only do the conversion one time. When reading the csv file, it takes time to do the conversion.

Comment: Best way as suggested by Shaido. As mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37330866/extract-date-from-a-string-column-containing-timestamp-in-pyspark

Comment: What does unix_timestamp do?

Answer (score 0):

I also had similar requirement . I used the below code to read the csv using infer schema option.

```
 Dataset<Row> data = sparkSession.read().format(fileType).option("header",header).option("inferSchema", "true").option("delimiter",delimeter).option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED").load(filePath);

Then i formatted the date using the below statement.
data=data.withColumn("the_date", to_date(unix_timestamp(col("the_date"), "mm/dd/yyyy").cast("timestamp")));
```